# Swipe Gesture used in application

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have issue regarding using swipe gesture.

Problem is that I want to perform both right and left swipe while holding click changing direction to left-right.

Can I use CCTouch methods for this condition? If yes then how can i use this? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: to detect both left & right swipes, you need to create and use two swipe gesture recognizers, one for left and one for right swipes

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, Sir please read my answer 1 comment

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
  ...
  ...
     [self createSwipeRecognizerView];

     return YES;

}



-(void) createSwipeRecognizerView {
    //NSLog(@"Creating Swipe Recognizer");

    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenDidswipe)];
    // swipeRightOnTable is the callback method in my case

    swipeRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
    // select swipe direction
    swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;

    [self.navController.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [recognizer release];
}

    -(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
    {
        if([[MyGame sharedGameObject].layer isKindOfClass:[MyGameScreen class]])
            return YES;
        return NO;
    }

    -(void) screenDidswipe 
    {
        MyGame *sGame = [MyGame sharedGameObject];
        if([sGame.layer isKindOfClass:[MyGameScreen class]])
        {
            [(MyGameScreen*)(sGame.layer) screenDidswipe];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am creating animation using 60 images and it looks like 3d modeling.But my problem is that when i click for swipe in left direction and suddenly i change the direction of swipe to right.practically it stop in left swipe and move into right but in not happens like that.

Comment: Please reply because i have still problem

Comment: @Leena, not getting what exactly u want..I used above code to detect swipe in game and it worked in cocos2d game.

Comment: Yes i know that, But my problem is different.I want something like that when i swipe left side then animation occur only left side and frame only pass the amount of swipe.

Comment: in above answer replace UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp with UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft. Then u get control for left swipe, then play corresponding animation...thats it